# Random cookie loss in IE and Edge

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies

In my web project, I have a csrf protection built-in so that I set a value to the cookie (httpOnly) at each request, which at the same time transfers (through html metadata) a javascript call (json) as an http header. On the server, before executing each json request, I check whether the cookie matches the value in the http header. In all browsers, except for Internet Explorer and the Edge, the protection is reliable. On the Internet Explorer and Edge, occasionally (1 in 1000 requests) that the json request does not contain a cookie. This problem persists until the client restores the page and does not reload the cookie. I add that this problem also occurs on another project that does not use javascript and is implemented by another framework (asp.net). Again only Internet Explorer and Edge. My colleague has discussed this issue with me and looked into the code, and she thinks this problem really is happening.

Does anyone have any experience with this problem?

Comment: Does this happen on all workstations/user ID's or just some.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your issue?